# Can Facebook app make a "question post" and then use the data from the answers to make analysis?

Tags: facebook

Facebook has question posts where you ask a question and provide a few options for people to select per their suitability. I want to know if a facebook app can create question posts and then use data from the answers to make analysis. Lets say there is an app and user ABC interacts with it, the app helps user ABC spit out a question to user ABC's social circle; then the app displays graphs of how people answered that question. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, Facebook Questions isn't available through their API or exposed via their FQL tables.  You should be able to get this information once they expose it to either of these two. If you can't wait, you could write your own app that takes the Facebook friends to a link to answer the question but it won't work as smoothly as their native [Facebook questions](https://www.facebook.com/questions/). You can suggest that they add this ability [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=ui_qa).

Answer (score 0):

They just added the ability to post questions (read has been available for a while)

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/